# Matching lines in files like grep -f

Tags: python, design-patterns, matching

I am trying to find matching lines in two large files, much like grep -f.
Let's say the file f.txt contains 3 lines:

```
1  
2  
3
```

and the file g.txt contains 3 lines:

```
3  
4  
5
```

and I want to print the matching line(s):

```
3
```

This is what I have tried:

```
f=open('f.txt', 'r')  
g=open('g.txt', 'r')  
i=0  
for line in f:  
    search = g.readlines()[i]  
    if line.strip() == search :  
        print line  
    i += 1
```

This returns the error

> > > 'AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: The code you posted cannot produce the error message you indicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to read the file that contains the lines you want to match into memory; otherwise you will have to read the entire file being searched for each line of the file containing the search terms. We'll do this using a `set` because checking to see if something is in a `set` is very fast.

```
with open("f.txt") as f:
    terms = set(line.strip() for line in f)

with open("g.txt") as g:
    for line in g:
       line = line.strip()
       if line in terms:
           print line
```

It doesn't matter in this case which file you consider the file containing the search terms and which you consider the file you're searching, since you are looking only for matches. To minimize memory use, you might choose the smaller one to be `f`.